# Symfony2 : form_row prototype in a loop

Tags: forms, symfony, loops, collections

I have an Entity Product to which I'm adding traductions (collection of ProductDescription).

Here is my ProductDescriptionType :

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('name')
        ->add('description', 'textarea')
        ->add('metaDescription', 'textarea')
        ->add('metaKeyword', 'textarea')
        ->add('tag')
        ->add('languageId', 'hidden')
    ;
}
```

And my ProductType:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('upc')
        ->add('model')
        ->add('sku')
        ->add('quantity')
        ->add('price')
        ->add('status', 'choice', 
            array(
                'choices'   => Product::getStatusArray(),
                'required'  => true,
            )
        )
    ;

    //ProductDescription 
    $builder->add('traductions', 'collection', 
        array(
            'type' => new ProductDescriptionType(),
            'allow_add'     => true,
            'prototype'     => true,
            'label'         => false,
            'by_reference'  => false
        )
    );
}
```

And in my view new.html.twig, I'm doing :

```
{% for language in languages %}
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="product-traduction-{{ language.languageId }}">
        {{ form_row(create_form.traductions.vars.prototype.languageId, {'value' : language.languageId }) }}
        {{ form_row(create_form.traductions.vars.prototype.name) }}
        {{ form_row(create_form.traductions.vars.prototype.description) }}
        {{ form_row(create_form.traductions.vars.prototype.metaDescription) }}
        {{ form_row(create_form.traductions.vars.prototype.metaKeyword) }}
        {{ form_row(create_form.traductions.vars.prototype.tag) }}
     </div>
 {% endfor %}
```

I'm not looping through create_form.traductions because it's empty (creation of a product), and I would like to have the fields of the ProductDescription already showing for all languages available.

The problem is that form_row only render the fields once.

I saw that this part is explained on the CookBook http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html, but it's done with JQuery and I have to do a lot of modification to the prototype inputs to achieve what I want (replace **name**, put languageId in the hidden input, etc).

Can someone help me please ?

Thanks for your time.